# How do I make a copy of a JPanel with all of its jcomponents having same functionalities as the original panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is a gui transformations project. I have a jcombobox that updates my jpanel jpTransDetails performing translation, rotation, etc upon selection on the corresponding jbutton. Now I have to work on another part where I want to have an exact copy of this jcomboBox and JPanel transformation details having the same functionalities as this. What is the best way to achieve this?

Please note that I have only shown you part of the code for it not to be lengthy. The parts are repeated for the other transformations.

UPDATE: I have tried creating a basic example of adding a new jpanel to a jpanel using a class but it does not work

```
   transNameList = new String[] {"Translation","Rotation","Scaling","Shear","Reflection"};
    jcbTranslations = new JComboBox(transNameList);

    mPane.add(jcbTranslations); //mPane is my main jpanel

    //transDetails JPANEL
    jpTransDetails = new JPanel(null);
    jpTransDetails.setBounds(10,95,320,103);
    jpTransDetails.setOpaque(false);
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white);
    jpTransDetails.setBorder(border);



    //TRANSLATION

    JLabel lblTx = new JLabel("Enter X-Coordinate: ");
    lblTx.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblTx.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    lblTx.setBounds(10,6,150,12);
    lblTx.setToolTipText("Number of units moved along x-axis");

    tTx = new JTextField();
    tTx.setText("0");
    tTx.setColumns(10);
    tTx.setBounds(175, 4, 50, 18);

    JLabel lblTy = new JLabel("Enter Y-Coordinate: ");
    lblTy.setForeground(Color.black);
    lblTy.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    lblTy.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 12);
    lblTy.setToolTipText("Number of units moved along y-axis");



    tTy = new JTextField();
    tTy.setText("0");
    tTy.setColumns(10);
    tTy.setBounds(175, 60, 50, 18);


    bTranslate = new JButton("TRANSLATE");
    bTranslate.setBounds(210,1,110, 25);
    bTranslate.setBackground(Color.black);
    bTranslate.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    //JPANEL FOR TRANSFORMATION BUTTON
    jpTransBtn =new JPanel(null);
    jpTransBtn.setBounds(10,200,320,28);
    jpTransBtn.setOpaque(false);

    jpTransDetails.setBounds(10,95,320,100);


    //ADDING FOR TRANSLATION 
    jpTransDetails.add(lblTx);
    jpTransDetails.add(tTx);
    jpTransDetails.add(lblTy);
    jpTransDetails.add(tTy);

    //ADDING TRANSLATION BUTTON
    jpTransBtn.add(bTranslate);

    mPane.add(jpTransDetails);
    mPane.add(jpTransBtn);


    //ITEM LISTENER FOR jcbTranslations
    jcbTranslations.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
            {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
                {
                    if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    {
                        if (jcbTranslations.getSelectedIndex()==0) //TRANSLATION
                        {
                            jpTransDetails.removeAll();
                            jpTransDetails.repaint();

                            jpTransBtn.removeAll();
                            jpTransBtn.repaint();

                            //ADDING FOR TRANSLATION 
                            jpTransDetails.add(lblTx);
                            jpTransDetails.add(tTx);
                            jpTransDetails.add(lblTy);
                            jpTransDetails.add(tTy);

                            //ADDING TRANSLATION BUTTON
                            jpTransBtn.add(bTranslate);


                        }

                        if (jcbTranslations.getSelectedIndex()==1) //ROTATION
                        {
                            jpTransDetails.removeAll();
                            jpTransDetails.repaint();

                            jpTransBtn.removeAll();
                            jpTransBtn.repaint();

                            //ADDING FOR ROTATION
                            jpTransDetails.add(lblRx);
                            jpTransDetails.add(Rotx);
                            jpTransDetails.add(lblRy);
                            jpTransDetails.add(Roty);
                            jpTransDetails.add(lblAngx);
                            jpTransDetails.add(tAngle);


                            //ADDING ROTATION BUTTON
                            jpTransBtn.add(bRotate);


                        }
```

UPDATE

```
   public class MainPanelClass extends JFrame   
   {
     public static JPanel selectionpanel;

     MainPanelClass()
     {
       selectionpanel = new JPanel();
       selectionpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
       selectionpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
       selectionpanel.add(new CompositeTransformationsPanel());
       add(selectionpanel);

     }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MainPanelClass mpc = new MainPanelClass();
      mpc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      mpc.setVisible(true);
      mpc.setSize(300,400);
  }
```

}

```
   This is my class extending a jpanel

   public class CompositeTransformationsPanel extends JPanel
   {
        CompositeTransformationsPanel()
        {
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,10));
          setBackground(Color.red);
          setOpaque(false);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to create a class who either extends JPanel or contains a JPanel by composition and whose job it is is to create this component of interest in exactly the same way every time. If you need both to share models, then you can give this class a copy constructor where it extracts the models from all components and puts those same models in the newly created JPanel.

Other recommendations:

- Avoid null layouts and `setBounds` as this leads to rigid GUI's that cannot adapt to different operating systems or uses. Much better to learn and use the layout managers.
- Try to separate your model code -- the non-GUI logic portion of your program, with the view -- the GUI portion, as much as possible. This will make it easier to achieve these sorts of things, and make it much easier to debug and test the code.
- Rather than removing and replacing components manually, much better to swap components using a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which makes it much easier and safer to swap

---

On review of your code, my recommendations have changed. It looks like you want to create input form for performing transformation on points, and you want to change the type of transformation depending on the selection made in the JComboBox. If so, my recommendations are:

- Possibly no need to create multiple similar JPanels and swap JPanels
- Instead use one single JPanel for the whole thing
- Give it a single JButton, say titled "Submit"
- Give that JButton an ActionListner
- In that listener, check the current state of the JComboBox, its selected item
- Do the appropriate calculation based on the selected item.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PointManipulationPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private JComboBox<Transform> transformCombo = new JComboBox<Transform>(Transform.values());
    private JTextField xCoordField = new JTextField("0", 5);
    private JTextField yCoordField = new JTextField("0", 5);

    public PointManipulationPanel() {   
        JPanel coordinatePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE);
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder, insideBorder);
        coordinatePanel.setBorder(border);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
        coordinatePanel.add(new JLabel("Enter X-Coordinate: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        coordinatePanel.add(new JLabel("Enter Y-Coordinate: "), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        coordinatePanel.add(xCoordField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        coordinatePanel.add(yCoordField, gbc);

        JPanel topPane = new JPanel();
        topPane.add(transformCombo);

        JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.addActionListener(e -> submitActionPerformed(e));
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(submitButton);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(topPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(coordinatePanel);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void submitActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        try {
            x = Integer.parseInt(xCoordField.getText());
            y = Integer.parseInt(yCoordField.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            // warn user with JOptionPane that data entered no goo
            String message = "Invalid number entry";
            String title = "Invalid Data";
            int messageType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(PointManipulationPanel.this, message, title, messageType);

            // exit method
            return;
        }

        // use x and y here in the calculations
        Transform transform = (Transform) transformCombo.getSelectedItem();
        switch (transform) {
        case TRANSLATION:
            // TODO: real code to do calculations goes here
            System.out.printf("Do translation here on x and y: [%d, %d]%n", x, y);
            break;
        case ROTATION:
            // TODO: real code to do calculations goes here
            System.out.printf("Do rotation here on x and y: [%d, %d]%n", x, y);
            break;
        case SCALING:
            // TODO: real code to do calculations goes here
            System.out.printf("Do scaling here on x and y: [%d, %d]%n", x, y);
            break;
        case SHEAR:
            // TODO: real code to do calculations goes here
            System.out.printf("Do shear here on x and y: [%d, %d]%n", x, y);
            break;
        case REFLECTION:
            // TODO: real code to do calculations goes here
            System.out.printf("Do reflection here on x and y: [%d, %d]%n", x, y);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value: " + transform);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            PointManipulationPanel mainPanel = new PointManipulationPanel();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```
enum Transform {
    TRANSLATION("Translation"), ROTATION("Rotation"), SCALING("Scaling"), SHEAR("Shear"), REFLECTION("Reflection");

    private String name;

    private Transform(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Ox12345: nobody said anything about making a class "static". The idea is to create the JPanel of interest with the same code and in the same way. Static has ***nothing*** to do with the solution to this problem.

Comment: @Ox12345 best if you could create and post a valid [mre] with your question, code I can compile, run and adapt and improve. Also images of GUI appearance can help

Comment: do i need to do something additional to make it visible? It is not showing up

Comment: @Ox12345: I have no idea -- you do understand that your posted code is of no use to us, that no one can compile, run or test it or see what it is you're trying to do. For this reason, all I can give are very vague and general recommendations, and I absolutely cannot guess why your code may not be working as desired. Again, please read the [mre] link, again, please try to create one of these, a new small program, not your entire program, one that compiles, runs and illustrates the essentials of your problem for us. Without this, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @Ox12345: also note that if you're giving mPane a null layout, then your JComboBox will likely not appear. Again, do not use a null layout.

Comment: @Ox12345: recommendation change: there may be no need to swap JPanels after all

Comment: what do you mean by jcombobox will not appear? it does appear though

Comment: @Ox12345: I still cannot run your code or test it. For an example of a valid [mre] that illustrates my point, try copying and pasting the entire code that I've posted above into one file called PointManipulationPanel.java, and run it, and you'll see how it works, and that it works, and that it is fully self-contained.

Comment: thanks for the attempt.. But since im more comfortable with simpler codes, can you tell me the issue with my update?

Comment: @Ox12345: yes, I can tell you, ***if you create and post code that I can compile, and run*** as I've been asking for all along. Again, please check my code as an example of exactly what it is I'm requesting, a self-contained complete but small program, small enough to post in your question as code-formatted text.

Comment: @Ox12345: and again, please read the [mre] link as it will tell you why I am requesting this, why it is important for you and for me, and why I'm getting somewhat frustrated that you keep show code that I cannot test

Comment: @Ox12345: I've put in a bit of effort and time to create my example code, and so I'm not asking you to do anything that I'm not willing to do myself

Comment: check the simple example in my update. I'll work from tht

Comment: @Ox12345: Your example code works fine if you don't make the CompositeTransformationsPanel opaque. But setting opaqueness to false, the background color will not show.

Comment: Thanks for  ur help. I will now use this basic concept for the project